# Downloads from web browsers randomly bypass my downloads folder and go directly to my iCloud drive (desktop)

Tags: icloud, folders, data-transfer, sudo, indexing

When I would download files, they would always automatically go into my downloads folder. I have not done anything recently except fix the indexing on this mac with a sudo command.

Shortly after, anytime I download something from Safari or Chrome, once a file was finished downloading I would see "removed" in the download status bar in my browser. And when I would look for the file it moved itself to my desktop which is linked to my iCloud.

Weirdly, when I would try to move the file back to my downloads folder, it would get spit back out to my desktop. When I move the file to a different folder, it will stay there.

It looks like nothing want to go in or stay in my downloads folder. So strange...

Any ideas what I might have messed up? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What was the actual sudo command that you did?

Comment: sudo mdutil -i on /